# Visual Studio not closing curled bracket

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For some reason, on a new computer, Visual Studio won't auto-close curled brackets.

```
if(Username.Text.Equals()) {
```

And it doesn't auto-close. Works perfectly on all other machines I've installed VS2010 on. And now it just won't.

And there doesn't seem to be a setting in the options menu to alter this behavior. What do I need to do?

Comment: are you serious? i haven't seen that before. which key to do that? i haven't seen that in c# but i have seen that in vb.net

Comment: I am working on a C# project. I just type that { and hit enter. And previously, that always auto-completed the }. And now it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: I also have to manually enter the closing bracket, at which point the code block is automatically formatted/indented. I've never had VS2010 automatically put a closing bracket for me. I thought that was the default? Are you sure the machines don't have an add-in or tool installed such as Resharper?

Comment: i am working with visual studio for more than five years now and with visual studio 2010 from the betas. and i have not heard of this. anyway this is not working on my machine :)

Comment: i would like to hear the comments of the upvoter first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is actually built in to vs2010. But you can install the [MS Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) ([Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)) Which will give you brace auto completion. this is quite a common add in so maybe the other copies of VS you have tried have it installed??

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio will auto-format matching pairs of brackets as you type, but I have never seen this on Visual Studio 'out of the box'.

According to [this Microsoft Connect entry](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/457238/c-automatic-closing-of-curly-braces), it's officially not on VS2010, having been cut due to time priority issues vs time constraints.

However, add ons like the free Microsoft [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef), or the not-so-free JetBrains [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will add this functionality for you. Perhaps you had one of these (or other similar) add-ons installed in the other computers you have previously worked on.