# why is Visual Studio 2012 not inserting brackets for me?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am moving over from Java in eclipse to C++ with visual studio ultimate 2013, and something is really bothering me. Every time I write a function i have to manually insert the end brackets, which other IDEs always filled for me. Is there some setting where i can enable auto insert?

Comment: Voting to close: "How do I use this particular piece of software?" is not a programming question, and is probably best answered by reading the funky manual. Although a very quick search (which you could have done yourself), suggest it didn't support this for C++ until the [2013 version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2013/07/05/visual-studio-2013-preview-c-automatic-brace-completion.aspx), but there are [extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d) for 2012.

Comment: You can look into [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

Comment: But @Bob, "How do I make this programming-specific software do this programming-specific task?" *is* a programming question.

Comment: @BoBTFish This kind of question about a particular piece of software [is on topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113087/147640).

Comment: @RobKennedy I really don't think this is on the same level as asking about a compiler option, or a debugger, or something like that, but even if you insist it is, this question shows zero research effort.

Comment: Then vote it down, @Bob, but it's still on topic.

Comment: I still disagree, but I feel like I've been shouted down here, so I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio not closing curled bracket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237725/visual-studio-not-closing-curled-bracket)

Answer (score 3):

That is one of the most annoying features in Eclipse, as I can type my own `}` just as fast as having some automated script do it ...

That said, this is what you want:  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d